# Deserialize Application Insights Analytics with Json.net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to use Json.net to deserialize JSON from Application Insights Analytics (AIA) into my class.  I'm not sure if I'm approaching it right, but I use LINQ-to-JSON to get at the data section of the JSON and then try to deserialize to my class using this code:

```
Dim rawjson As String = GetTelemetry()
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawjson)
Dim ds = DirectCast(o("Tables")(0)("Rows"), JArray)
Dim Sessions As List(Of Session) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Session))(ds)
```

This fails as the JSON from AIA is in this format:

```
"Rows": [
    [
      "Boy",
      "9",
      "",
      "",
      "0",
      "0",
      "22",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "Boy",
      "9",
      "",
      "",
      "0",
      "0",
      "41",
      "0"
    ],
```

Notice the data for the individual rows is an array rather than an object.

My `Session` class is defined like this:

```
Public Class Session
    Public Property Gender As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property SessionVids As Integer
    Public Property TotalVids As Integer
    Public Property ChildUse As Integer
    Public Property ChildTime As Integer
    Public Property AdultUse As Integer
    Public Property AdultTime
End Class
```

Can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: What is the definition of the `Session` class that you are trying to deserialize into?

Comment: Public Class Session
    Public Property Gender As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property SessionVids As Integer
    Public Property TotalVids As Integer
    Public Property ChildUse As Integer
    Public Property ChildTime As Integer
    Public Property AdultUse As Integer
    Public Property AdultTime
End Class

Comment: @BrianRogers any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `JArray` of rows (`ds`) into a list of `Session` objects like this:

```
Dim Sessions As List(Of Session) =
    ds.Select(Function(ja)
                  Dim s As New Session()
                  s.Gender = ja(0).Value(Of String)()
                  s.Age = GetInt(ja(1))
                  s.SessionVids = GetInt(ja(2))
                  s.TotalVids = GetInt(ja(3))
                  s.ChildUse = GetInt(ja(4))
                  s.ChildTime = GetInt(ja(5))
                  s.AdultUse = GetInt(ja(6))
                  s.AdultTime = GetInt(ja(7))
                  Return s
              End Function).ToList()
```

where `GetInt` is a helper function defined like this:

```
Public Function GetInt(jt As JToken) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(jt.Value(Of String)(), i)
        Return i
    End If
    Return 0
End Function
```

The helper function is needed since the JSON has empty strings for some of the values while your class requires valid integers.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GqFcov